# How to delete AWS Cloud front invalidation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have some invalidations created on my AWS accounts that are no longer required. I tried to find ways to delete/remove them using console or AWS CLI but couldn't find any. I was just wondering the way I may delete them from my account. Appreciate any response.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove invalidations from the list. Once invalidation is complete, it merely becomes and audit log entry. Hence deleting it would have no effect.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#Invalidation_Requests